# For loop not printing the items

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, list-comprehension, python-itertools

I am generating combinations using `itertools` and am trying to print every combination.
Both `for` loop and list comprehension fail at this simple task.

```
In [1]: from itertools import combinations

In [2]: combos = combinations(range(3), 2)

In [3]: list(combos)
Out[3]: [(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2)]

In [4]: for comb in combos:
   ...:     print(comb)

In [5]: [comb for comb in combos]
Out[5]: []
```

Any ideas about why I don't see all combinations?

Comment: It's an iterator. You depleted it with `list(combos)`. After that it's got zero elements, so there are no `comb` left to display.

Comment: I am simply printing `list(combos)` to show that it is not empty.

Comment: @TemporalWolf : True!! I am so stupid!

Comment: I think it's a pretty reasonable mistake, especially given your two test cases silently hide the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an `iterator`. You depleted it with `list(combos)`. After that it's got zero elements, so there are no `comb` left to display:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> combos = itertools.combinations(range(3),2)
>>> combos
<itertools.combinations object at 0x0000000004BB66D8>
>>> list(combos)
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2)]
>>> combos.next()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
>>> len(combos)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: object of type 'itertools.combinations' has no len()
```

`combos` is **not** a list. It's an `iterator`... and once you finish all the terms it throws a `StopIteration` exception, but a `list comprehension` and a `for loop` both end on `StopIteration`, so they just run zero times.

You can, however, do:

```
combos = list(itertools.combinations(range(3),2))
```

which will convert it to a list and lists can be traversed indefinitely.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you need it seems like list(combos) empties out the combination.

```
>>> combos = combinations(range(3), 2)
>>> list(combos)
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2)]
>>> list(combos)
[]
```

So you need to declare it as a list, and then parse it.

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> combos = combinations(range(3), 2)
>>> combo_list = list(combos)
>>> for comb in combo_list:    
...     print(comb)
... 
(0, 1)
(0, 2)
(1, 2)
>>> 
>>> [comb for comb in combo_list]
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2)]
```